# Oracle BPM Invoke Service with Human Task - times out

Tags: business-process-management, oracle-soa

I have a BPM process that calls another process (In a different project).

The child process is a synchronous process with a human task in it and it retuns an object.  The parent process invokes the child process through a Service task, but I get an issue when doing so.  The invocation of the child process times out with

`Waiting for response has timed out. The conversation id is urn:9F38B060CE6811E3BFF4AF3AE1582E39. Please check the process instance for detail.`

I have tried invoking the child through a Throw Message mechanism - but I get another error when doing that:

`IDeliveryService.post() invoked for two-way operation 'receiveSDFValidationErrorsReport'. This method can only be used to invoke one-way operations which don't return any messages. Please check the WSDL which defines this operation and use the method IDeliveryService.request() to invoke a two-way operation`

I do not see a way to define a throw message where I explicitly capture the return.  How do I invoke a service that is synchronous and contains a human task (which could sit idle for long periods of time) without having it time out?

Answer (score 1):

If the child process has an user task on it, then the call should be asynchronous, using send and receive task or message events